# SSR в окружении PHP и Vue.js

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, ssr

Стоит жирная задача реализовать [SSR (Server-Side Rendering)](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/ssr.html) в проекте, но постоянно вылазят разные трудности.

В первую очередь мне нужен SSR без вмешательства сервера Node.js, по документации на Vue, такое возможно, и [тут показано как](https://ssr.vuejs.org/ru/guide/non-node.html).

Теперь главная проблема..

Постоянно отображаются ошибки `window is not defined` и `document is not defined`. Я понимаю почему это происходит и в своём коде уже перекрыл доступ к `window` и `document` через SSR. Но проблема в том что данные ошибки отображаются из-за бесчисленного кол-ва используемых библиотек, и даже из файла самого vue.js

Ничего стоящего не могу найти в интернете. Буду рад любой помощи.

EDIT1:

Исправил проблему с библиотеками и с файлом vue.js.

Теперь выдает ошибку `Error: render function or template not defined in component`

Строка указывает на этот фрагмент кода:

```
renderVueComponentToString(app.app, (err, res) => {
    if (err) throw new Error(err); // А именно на эту строку
    print(res);
});
```

Я БУДУ УЖЕ БЛАГОДАРЕН ХОТЯ БЫ РАБОЧЕМУ ПРИМЕРУ

webpack.build.config.js

```
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const baseWebpackConfig = require('./webpack.base.conf');
const PATHS = baseWebpackConfig.externals.paths;

const buildWebpackConfig = merge(baseWebpackConfig, {
    mode: 'production',
    target: 'node',
    node: undefined,
    externals: undefined,
    entry: {
        server: PATHS.src + '/js/entry-server.js'
    },
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: false,
        minimizer: [
            new UglifyJsPlugin({
                include: /\.min\.js$/,
                cache: true,
                parallel: true,
                uglifyOptions: {
                    compress: false,
                    ecma: 8,
                    mangle: true,
                    output: {
                        comments: false,
                    },
                },
                sourceMap: true
            })
        ]
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader',
                options: {
                    loader: {
                        scss: 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader'
                    },
                    extractCSS: false,
                    optimizeSSR: false,
                }
            }
        ]
    }
});

module.exports = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(buildWebpackConfig);
});
```

entry-server.js

```
import { createApp } from './main';

const app = createApp();

renderVueComponentToString(app.app, (err, res) => {
    if (err) throw new Error(err);
    print(res);
});
```

main.js

```
import '../sass/main.sass';

import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.min';

// Импорт библиотек

// Импорт компонентов

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

export function createApp() {

    Vue.component('component1', Component1);
    Vue.component('component2', Component2);
    Vue.component('component3', Component3);

    const app = new Vue({
        components: {
            component4: Component4,
            component5: Component5
        },
        data: {
            // Ненужный код
        },
        created() {
            if (!this.isSSR) {
                // Ненужный код
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            if (!this.isSSR) {
                // Ненужный код
            }
        },
        computed: {
            isSSR() {
                return typeof window === 'undefined' || typeof document === 'undefined';
            },
            // Ненужный код
        },
        methods: {
            // Ненужный код
        },
    });

    return { app };
}
```

SSR РЕАЛИЗОВЫВАЛ С ЭТОГО ПРИМЕРА: https://github.com/delphinpro/vue-ssr-with-php-v8js

Comment: Это вопрос к библиотекам, которые Вы используете. Смотрите их документацию...и, кстати, файл vue, скорее всего, тоже они используют.

Comment: @Дмытрык Решил проблему с библиотеками, теперь главная и надеюсь последняя проблема в том, что файл vue использует у себя document на стороне сервера. Я полазил, проблема конкретно в функции `query(el)` которая ищет dom элементы. А ищет она скорее всего мой `#app` при инициализации Vue.

Comment: Покажите ошибку. Мой  vue-ssr ничем таким не занимается

Comment: @Дмытрык Ошибка максимально проста: `document is not defined`. Строка указывает на тело функции `query(el)` в файле `vue.js`, а конкретно в строке `var selected = document.querySelector(el);`. Функция вызывается при инициализации Vue, чтобы найти DOM-элемент `#app`.

Comment: @Дмытрык Я не исключаю что мог допустить банальные ошибки, так как работаю с SSR впервые. Но у меня есть [работающий пример](https://github.com/delphinpro/vue-ssr-with-php-v8js), SSR которого я пытаюсь внедрить в свой проект.

Comment: В общем случае вы не должны указывать опцию `el` при создании корневого экземпляра и не должны использовать метод [`.$mount()`](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/index.html#vm-mount) на стороне сервера. Возможно, ошибка из-за этого. Но без вашего кода что-то определенное сказать сложно.

Comment: @Dmitry Спасибо, Дмитрий. В ближайшее время добавлю.

Comment: @Dmitry Дурацкая ошибка, вы были абсолютно правы насчет `el`, исправил это. Теперь выбивает `Error: render function or template not defined in component`. Сейчас добавлю код.

Comment: покажите файл `main.js`

Comment: @Дмытрык Добавил

Comment: 1) Очень много компонентов используете как для первого запуска Vue на PHP. 2) Ваш код совсем не такой как в документации https://ssr.vuejs.org/ru/guide/non-node.html  и в нем действительно нет template и метода render

Comment: @Дмытрык Понял, тогда попробую создать корневой компонент App, всё переместить туда и попробую снова. Спасибо.

Comment: @Дмытрык К сожалению это ничего не изменило. И да, мой код не такой как в документации, но пример с которого я взял полностью рабочий.

Comment: @Дмытрык Есть возможность запустить код без метода render?

Comment: В Nodejs окружении, метод render не используется. Я с РНР не работаю, поэтому могу только догадываться,  что да как. Но на Вашем месте, я бы отложил  в сторону этот, якобы работающий, пример и запустил бы код из документации.

Comment: https://rojas.io/vue-js-server-side-rendering-with-php/  https://dzone.com/articles/server-side-rendering-with-laravel-amp-vuejs-25  может поможет

Comment: @Дмытрык Спасибо за помощь. Та дело в том что я уже попробовал и чисто как в документации, та же ошибка.

Comment: @Дмытрык Туго с этим в интернете. К сожалению первая ссылка рассказывает как запустить SSR в окружение PHP, но с помощью Node.js, а вторая без Node.js, но только для Laravel фреймворка, с ним на данный момент не работаю. Всё что есть полезное на эту тему, это SSR для Laravel и одна страничка документации на сайте Vue. Буду дальше думать, спасибо.

Comment: Может быть вам [это](https://github.com/NightCatSama/vue-slider-component/issues/114#issuecomment-353827607) поможет?

Comment: @radar4ick Видел это;) На первый взгляд тоже решил что должно помочь, но по факту там настраивается конфиг Nuxt.js, которые в свою очередь работает на базе Node.js. А мне пока что нужен SSR, без вмешательства Node.js

Comment: это не помощь в решении, а просьба поделиться решением, если таковое есть.я не понял как это правильно сделать и делаю в комментарии. надеюсь так разрешено использовать комментарии. за это время Вы наверное уже решили вопрос. не поделитесь ли с сообществом хотя бы полезными ссылками? стоит практически та же задача и так же ничего полезного не нахожу. если надо, сделаю отдельный вопрос, чтобы Вам там ответ написать.

Comment: @romanown К сожалению в данном контексте внятного ответа так и не появилось.

Comment: спасибо. получается, несмотря на заявление, что vue можно применить на имеющемся сайте, потихоньку на него переходя, не совсем соответствуют желаемому. а так же если использовать все в стандартном виде, то будет проблема с сео, поскольку сам хтмл код формируется у клиента, а не отдается сервером. у меня сайт сделан на пхп и jquery. хотел начать переходить на vue ничего не теряя, но похоже не получится. понадеялся на Ваш опыт, но за такое время и у Вас ничего не получилось, значит это невозможно. все что сам нашел, похоже на те ссылки, что тут приведены. может все же кто-то решил и поделится?

Comment: поскольку реального ответа нет, вот мой вариант. возможно кого-то это натолкнет на более правильное решение. я сделал основной код на php, который отдает сайт в виде полного html. а в дальнейшем через шаблоны vue уже управляет поведением страницы. при этом приходится выполнять двойную работу делая два макета, один формируется на php, второй уже со всем что нужно для vue. таким образом не ломается старое, но добавляется новое. это решение не правильное с точки зрения документации, но позволяет заменить JQuery и оставить рендеринг страниц для SEO посредством формирования их при помощи php.

Comment: Вы на своем опыте просто убедились еще раз что самостоятельно реализовать SSR не так просто. Почему просто не взять уже готовый фреймворк https://nuxtjs.org/ ?

Comment: Посмотрите вот эту статью. Там правда про react - но автор показывает как собрать статические страницы во время build из страниц написанных на react
https://medium.flatstack.com/landing-page-with-react-38-kb-of-js-100-100-performance-score-in-lighthouse-1dc798533c0b