# Vue+PHP+render, возможно ли?

Tags: php, vue.js, vue-cli

Всех приветствую!
Есть сайт, написанный на PHP. У него есть страница каталога, где настроено все SEO.
Ради ускорения появилась идея написать рендер страницы на Vue, но при этом оставить и серверную часть.

**Появились вопросы:**
1) Можно использовать vue cli с однофайловыми компонентами, генерируя index.php страницу вместо index.html.
2) Будет ли скрипт vue выполняться на готовом html коде, который отдаст php файл? я понимаю, что в теории нет, но нужно мнение знающих людей
3) Есть ли способ еще лучше это все организовать?

Comment: Сложный у Вас вопрос. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/999516/ssr-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-php-%d0%b8-vue-js

Comment: Ответ на 2- й вопрос - будет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам спросил, сам и отвечу:
**1) Не желательно!** 
НО можно просто генерировать через webpack готовый bundle. Настройки webpack'а:

```
{
    "name": <your-project-name>,
    "scripts": {
        "watch": "webpack -w",
        "build": "webpack"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "vue-loader": "^15.7.1",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10",
        "webpack": "^4.41.1",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.3.9"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "vue": "^2.6.10"
    }
}
```

**2) Теория подтвердилась**, при загрузке страницы vue инициализирует рендеринг по виртуальному дому. При рендеринге, умная система понимает, что дом не изменен, и вставлять (обновлять) ничего не надо. 
След если у нас есть готовый html с сервера, то vue инициализируется без обновления реального DOM дерева

**3) Тут уже дело каждого, под какие задачи он использует vue**